# Rendering Nested Comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, rendering, nested-sets

I typically render comments in a simple repeater.

I have a social app which requires nested comments (being able to comment on a comment).

So I have objects which look like this:

```
class Comment
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }
}
```

Can I use nested repeaters? Is that even a good idea? Do I need to pre-render the HTML in a recursive loop and send it to a literal?

Not sure what to do with this one.

Comment: The simple answer is yes repeaters can be placed inside of other repeaters, but this gets ugly.

Comment: Yes you can, bind the DataSource in ItemDataBound of the outer repeater. If you need it, you get the outer repeater from the inner repeater's ItemDataBound by casting the RepeaterItem's NamingContainer.

Comment: Is that a good way to handle this, though? It sounds terribly messy.

Comment: Nested Comments are essentially a tree, so something recursive sounds right. Not sure if I can do that with a control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an HTML source block, then iterate through the comments, adding a <DIV> for each comment begin, then after each comment, call the iterator on the nest list for that comment, then add the closing </DIV>

Comment: So have a `const string` running through a recursive loop that applies string.format() or something of the like? Essentially build the HTML as a string, and then assign it as a literal?

Comment: Yeah. A lot less expensive on the server than all those usercontrols.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use UserControls here.  Make a user control for a comment that knows how to render itself, and has 0...N other CommentUserControls (possibly rendered using a repeater).  This effectively ends up with nested repeaters (kinda) but by encapsulating one of the repeaters in a UserControl it should make it less messy.

Comment: I like this idea for a solution that is repeatable adn re-usable, but this doesn't help actually get to that solution.